# Need the position/index of a std::set element on find

Tags: c++

I use a std::set to sort a vector of unordered duplicate values. Every time I find an element in my set, I need to know the position (index) of the element as well. There are a lot of elements (hundreds of thousands) in my set, and using std::distance() gives me abysmal performance.

Is std::distance the only way to go?

Comment: if you are going to sort the vector, then you shouldn't need to use a set. Once you have a sorted vector, just use binary_search on it. I find the std::set to be rather slow.

Comment: Given your approach, why do you need the position? find returns the iterator, and you can move things around using those iterators. See std::swap, for example.

Comment: I'm cleaning a data structure that's a mesh, which uses indices to define polygons. After looking up a given vertex, I need its index in that list as well.

Comment: Are you trying to remove duplicates?  If so, then just use `std::sort` followed by `std::unique`.  Or perhaps use `std::set` instead of `std::vector` from the onset, and then you'll always have sorted, unique values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can sort the elements in place using the std::sort() algorithm.  Then when you find an element in the vector using binary_search() just subtract the result of a call to begin() from the iterator pointing to the element.

Another alternative is to use std::partial_sort_copy() if you don't want to overwrite your original vector.  Just sort into another vector and you can do the same thing I described above.